# Question about the singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with full rank and $m \geq n$. Let $R^T R $ be the cholesky factorization of $A^TA$.

can we assume that $A$ has the same nonzero singular values and corresponding right singular vectors as $R$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Since $A$ is of full column rank, the matrix $A^TA$ is non-singular, which makes $R$ non-singular too and
$$
A^TA=R^TR\quad \Rightarrow\quad R^{-T}A^T\underbrace{AR^{-1}}_{W}=I\quad \Rightarrow\quad W^TW=I.
$$
Now $A=WR$, and for the SVD of $R=U\cdot\Sigma\cdot V^T$ we get that $A=WU\cdot \Sigma\cdot  V^T$ is the SVD of $A$.